# MoveIt octomap not displayed in rviz

Tags: kinect, ros, voxel, moveit

I am working with **ROS INDIGO**, a **Sawyer** robot (Rethink robotics), a **Kinect v1**, and **MoveIt**. 
I am working on a Human-Robot Collaboration project.

After installing MoveIt, I have edited "camera_link_pose" from sawyer_moveit.launch to suit my base_to_camera transform. 
When I run:

```
roslaunch sawyer_moveit_config sawyer_moveit.launch electric_gripper:=true kinect:=true
```

Rviz appears, everything works except that **the octomap isn't displayed**:

[rviz_capture.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Cic.png)

Here is what I have in the terminal:

```
~/ros_ws$ roslaunch sawyer_moveit_config sawyer_moveit.launch electric_gripper:=true kinect:=true

... logging to /home/sawyer/.ros/log/33db5810-3ace-11e7-860e-1866da494b18/roslaunch-sawyer-HP-Compaq-Pro-6300-SFF-20862.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://169.254.5.155:38982/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /move_group/allow_trajectory_execution: True
 * /move_group/allowed_execution_duration_scaling: 1.2
 * /move_group/allowed_goal_duration_margin: 0.5
 * /move_group/camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads: 4
 * /move_group/camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
 * /move_group/camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
 * /move_group/camera/disparity_depth/max_range: 4.0
 * /move_group/camera/disparity_depth/min_range: 0.5
 * /move_group/camera/disparity_registered_hw/max_range: 4.0
 * /move_group/camera/disparity_registered_hw/min_range: 0.5
 * /move_group/camera/disparity_registered_sw/max_range: 4.0
 * /move_group/camera/disparity_registered_sw/min_range: 0.5
 * /move_group/camera/driver/data_skip: 0
 * /move_group/camera/driver/debug: False
 * /move_group/camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url: 
 * /move_group/camera/driver/depth_frame_id: camera_depth_opti...
 * /move_group/camera/driver/depth_registration: False
 * /move_group/camera/driver/device_id: #1
 * /move_group/camera/driver/diagnostics_max_frequency: 30.0
 * /move_group/camera/driver/diagnostics_min_frequency: 30.0
 * /move_group/camera/driver/diagnostics_tolerance: 0.05
 * /move_group/camera/driver/diagnostics_window_time: 5.0
 * /move_group/camera/driver/enable_depth_diagnostics: False
 * /move_group/camera/driver/enable_ir_diagnostics: False
 * /move_group/camera/driver/enable_rgb_diagnostics: False
 * /move_group/camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url: 
 * /move_group/camera/driver/rgb_frame_id: camera_rgb_optica...
 * /move_group/capabilities: move_group/MoveGr...
 * /move_group/controller_list: [{'default': True...
 * /move_group/controller_manager_name: simple_controller...
 * /move_group/head/planner_configs: ['SBLkConfigDefau...
 * /move_group/jiggle_fraction: 0.05
 * /move_group/max_range: 5.0
 * /move_group/max_safe_path_cost: 1
 * /move_group/move_group/octomap_frame: camera_link
 * /move_group/move_group/octomap_resolution: 0.02
 * /move_group/move_group/point_subsample: 1
 * /move_group/move_group/sensors: [{'max_range': 5....
 * /move_group/moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_con...
 * /move_group/moveit_manage_controllers: True
 * /move_group/octomap_resolution: 0.025
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::BKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/ESTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::EST
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/KPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::KPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECEkConfigDefault/type: geometric::LBKPIECE
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMkConfigDefault/max_nearest_neighbors: 10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PRM
 * /move_group/planner_configs/PRMstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::PRMstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnectkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnectkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRTCon...
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRT
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/delay_collision_checking: 1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/RRTstarkConfigDefault/type: geometric::RRTstar
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBLkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/SBLkConfigDefault/type: geometric::SBL
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/frountierNodeRatio: 0.1
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/frountier_threshold: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/init_temperature: 10e-6
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/k_constant: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/max_states_failed: 10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/min_temperature: 10e-10
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/range: 0.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/temp_change_factor: 2.0
 * /move_group/planner_configs/TRRTkConfigDefault/type: geometric::TRRT
 * /move_group/planning_plugin: ompl_interface/OM...
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_geometry_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_planning_scene: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_state_updates: True
 * /move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_transforms_updates: True
 * /move_group/request_adapters: default_planner_r...
 * /move_group/right_arm/planner_configs: ['SBLkConfigDefau...
 * /move_group/start_state_max_bounds_error: 0.1
 * /move_group/use_controller_manager: True
 * /robot_description_kinematics/head/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /robot_description_kinematics/head/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /robot_description_kinematics/head/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /robot_description_kinematics/head/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
 * /robot_description_kinematics/right_arm/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /robot_description_kinematics/right_arm/kinematics_solver_attempts: 10
 * /robot_description_kinematics/right_arm/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /robot_description_kinematics/right_arm/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j0/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j0/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j0/max_acceleration: 3.5
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j0/max_velocity: 0.88
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j1/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j1/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j1/max_acceleration: 2.5
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j1/max_velocity: 0.678
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j2/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j2/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j2/max_acceleration: 5.0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j2/max_velocity: 0.996
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j3/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j3/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j3/max_acceleration: 5.0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j3/max_velocity: 0.996
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j4/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j4/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j4/max_acceleration: 5.0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j4/max_velocity: 1.776
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j5/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j5/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j5/max_acceleration: 5.0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j5/max_velocity: 1.776
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j6/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j6/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j6/max_acceleration: 5.0
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/right_j6/max_velocity: 2.316
 * /robot_description_semantic: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21
 * /rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334/head/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334/head/kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
 * /rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334/head/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334/head/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
 * /rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334/right_arm/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334/right_arm/kinematics_solver_attempts: 10
 * /rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334/right_arm/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334/right_arm/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005

NODES
  /move_group/camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_hw_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_sw_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_hw (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_sw (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    ir_rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_hw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
    rgb_debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    rgb_rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rgb_rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
  /move_group/
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_link_broadcaster (tf/static_transform_publisher)
  /
    move_group (moveit_ros_move_group/move_group)
    rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334 (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://021611CP00073.local:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[move_group/camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [20874]
process[move_group/camera/driver-2]: started with pid [20875]
process[move_group/camera/rgb_debayer-3]: started with pid [20876]
process[move_group/camera/rgb_rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [20877]
process[move_group/camera/rgb_rectify_color-5]: started with pid [20878]
process[move_group/camera/ir_rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [20879]
process[move_group/camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [20883]
process[move_group/camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [20890]
process[move_group/camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [20891]
process[move_group/camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [20902]
process[move_group/camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [20906]
process[move_group/camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [20907]
process[move_group/camera/depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-13]: started with pid [20919]
process[move_group/camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-14]: started with pid [20923]
process[move_group/camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15]: started with pid [20926]
[ INFO] [1495016462.598547792]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[move_group/camera/depth_registered_hw_metric_rect-16]: started with pid [20927]
process[move_group/camera/depth_registered_metric-17]: started with pid [20941]
process[move_group/camera/disparity_depth-18]: started with pid [20946]
process[move_group/camera/disparity_registered_sw-19]: started with pid [20948]
process[move_group/camera/disparity_registered_hw-20]: started with pid [20952]
process[move_group/camera_base_link-21]: started with pid [20953]
process[move_group/camera_base_link1-22]: started with pid [20965]
process[move_group/camera_base_link2-23]: started with pid [20969]
process[move_group/camera_base_link3-24]: started with pid [20980]
process[move_group/camera_link_broadcaster-25]: started with pid [20984]
process[move_group-26]: started with pid [20986]
process[rviz_sawyer_HP_Compaq_Pro_6300_SFF_20862_7403073962417655334-27]: started with pid [20993]
[ INFO] [1495016462.693509168]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1495016462.693602953]: 1. device on bus 000:00 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00366907653103A'
[ INFO] [1495016462.694673734]: Searching for device with index = 1

(rviz:20993): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
[ INFO] [1495016462.750378327]: rviz version 1.11.15
[ INFO] [1495016462.750424452]: compiled against Qt version 4.8.6
[ INFO] [1495016462.750436423]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
[ INFO] [1495016462.778280205]: Starting a 3s RGB and Depth stream flush.
[ INFO] [1495016462.778359537]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 0:0 with serial number 'A00366907653103A'
[ INFO] [1495016462.779418408]: Loading robot model 'sawyer'...
[ INFO] [1495016462.859296395]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1495016462.859370647]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
[ WARN] [1495016462.895187551]: Could not find any compatible depth output mode for 1. Falling back to default depth output mode 1.
[ INFO] [1495016462.938451761]: Loading robot model 'sawyer'...
[ INFO] [1495016462.996939730]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1495016463.005977717]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
Starting context monitors...
[ INFO] [1495016463.006036440]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1495016463.016688848]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1495016463.016734632]: Starting world geometry monitor
[ INFO] [1495016463.025046719]: Listening to '/collision_object' using message notifier with target frame '/base '
[ INFO] [1495016463.033351917]: Listening to '/planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[ INFO] [1495016463.062230866]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
Context monitors started.
[ INFO] [1495016463.110704157]: Initializing OMPL interface using ROS parameters
[ INFO] [1495016463.159454318]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[ INFO] [1495016463.189799983]: Param 'default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10
[ INFO] [1495016463.192609516]: Param 'start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.1
[ INFO] [1495016463.195020096]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1495016463.197465266]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1495016463.201089427]: Param 'jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.05
[ INFO] [1495016463.203597709]: Param 'max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[ INFO] [1495016463.203654817]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Parameterization'
[ INFO] [1495016463.203682529]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[ INFO] [1495016463.203711417]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[ INFO] [1495016463.203723132]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[ INFO] [1495016463.203761613]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[ WARN] [1495016463.215644770]: 
Deprecation warning: parameter 'allowed_execution_duration_scaling' moved into namespace 'trajectory_execution'.
Please, adjust file trajectory_execution.launch.xml!
[ WARN] [1495016463.217830741]: 
Deprecation warning: parameter 'allowed_goal_duration_margin' moved into namespace 'trajectory_execution'.
Please, adjust file trajectory_execution.launch.xml!
[ INFO] [1495016463.481330910]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for /robot/limb/right
[ INFO] [1495016463.481450028]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1495016463.516304840]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPickPlaceAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[ INFO] [1495016463.767432287]: 

********************************************************
* MoveGroup using: 
*     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
*     - ClearOctomapService
*     - CartesianPathService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
*     - GetPlanningSceneService
*     - KinematicsService
*     - MoveAction
*     - PickPlaceAction
*     - MotionPlanService
*     - QueryPlannersService
*     - StateValidationService
********************************************************

[ INFO] [1495016463.767507058]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1495016463.767531704]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

All is well! Everyone is happy! You can start planning now!

[ INFO] [1495016463.848688873]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1495016463.848798099]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1495016463.876687681]: Camera calibration file /home/sawyer/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00366907653103A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1495016463.876777590]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1495016463.876814517]: Camera calibration file /home/sawyer/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00366907653103A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1495016463.876862956]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
[ INFO] [1495016465.779364068]: Stopping device RGB and Depth stream flush.
[ INFO] [1495016466.428636329]: Loading robot model 'sawyer'...
[ INFO] [1495016466.532779604]: Loading robot model 'sawyer'...
[ INFO] [1495016466.585212741]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1495016466.592453780]: Listening to '/move_group/monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1495016467.461837577]: No active joints or end effectors found for group ''. Make sure you have defined an end effector in your SRDF file and that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.
[ INFO] [1495016467.469390902]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'right_arm' in namespace ''
[ INFO] [1495016468.301998541]: TrajectoryExecution will use old service capability.
[ INFO] [1495016468.302066666]: Ready to take MoveGroup commands for group right_arm.
[ INFO] [1495016468.302105415]: Looking around: no
[ INFO] [1495016468.302133111]: Replanning: no
```

I think I have tried almost everything to make it work. I followed several tutorial but my configuration seems to be ok. Here are some documentation I've been through:

**MoveIt tutorials:**
http:// docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/doc/perception_configuration.html

**MoveIt google group:**
https:// groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/moveit-users

**Baxter Kinect integration for MoveIt:**
http:// sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Kinect_basics

**MoveIt installation and tuto for Sawyer**
http:// sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/intera/MoveIt_Tutorial

It seems that I am not the only one **not being able to see the octomap in rviz**. Maybe someone here had already been confronted to this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, check here if you are interested: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/Fz-Hxhjr5zI

There is a useless "move_group" namespace block in "sawyer_moveit_sensor_manager.launch.xml"